# Asking Global Variable Set In Template Within Node

Tags: php, drupal

Within a Drupal theme, page.tpl.php, I'm setting a COOKIE/GLOBAL variable.

However, when I try accessing the Cookie or Global within the node page content, it is always blank.  If I reload the page I can finally access the cookie.  Is there no way to pass the set variable to the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cookie that set with `setcookie()` is visible in `$_COOKIE` superglobal **only** on next request.

this happens because cookies are stored on a client and are passed with request. obviously on the first request there is no such cookie, and `setcookie()` doesn't modify that superglobal.

Comment: Yeh, thats why I set the same variable in a $GLOBALS.  However I still can't access that $GLOBALS within the node.

Comment: @Chain: there are several possible reasons why code behave in this way: 1) you query `$_GLOBAL` *before* you've put data to it 2) You haven't put the data to it 3) some code removed the data you've put